# How to use Picasso library to crop a picture not from the middle but from the top?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, picasso

There is a method `cropCentre()` - it crops in the middle. So is there any similar method, like `topCentre()` for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always apply a custom transformation to the fetched `Bitmap`:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(uri).transform(new Transformation() {
        @Override
        public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
            ///Do what you want with bitmap
            return source;
        }

        @Override
        public String key() {
            return null;
        }
    }).into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Picasso extension picasso-transformations should have the transformation you need: [picasso transformations](https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations)